# Squaring the Circle

Tags: soft-question

Is squaring the circle possible in any sort of metric at all? It's known that within the Euclidean metric it is impossible, but does there exist some world or space where it is possible? Much like how $x^2+1$ has no solutions in the real field, but it does have solutions in the complex field.

Comment: Is Taxicab Geometry allowed?

Comment: Any sort of metric is allowed, I just want to see what metrics there are out there that allow such a thing.

Comment: I recollect that there are no Circles in Taxicab Geometry: all lines are either mutually parallel or perpendicular, as in the Manhattan Grid of New York City (you can only drive North and South, or East and West.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. On the ordinary sphere of radius $1,$ there are countably many pairs of "squares" and circles with equal areas, where both the (geodesic) radius of the circle and the length of the four sides of the square can be constructed. The limit of this is when both are a hemisphere, regarded as a square with four angles all equal to $\pi.$

Similar in the hyperbolic plane, countable number of pairs.

In both cases, there is no procedure for beginning with a circle of unknown radius and constructing the square with equal area, or for starting with a square of unknown edge length and producing the circle with equal area. Both figures must be constructed at the sam time, you might say.

[See my article in the Intelligencer at](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf) and Marvin's article at http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/old-and-new-results-in-the-foundations-of-elementary-plane-euclidean-and-non-euclidean-geometries

Comment: "See my article in the Intelligencer at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/bib.html".  I click, not found.  Please update.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf    The server that hosted my pages died.

Comment: Please put this update into the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We usually define a circle of radius $r$ about a point $(x_0,y_0)$
in an $x,y$ coordinate plane by using the Euclidean metric $\|x,y\|_2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}:$
we set $\|x-x_0, y-y_0\|_2 = r.$

If instead we use the taxicab metric, $\|x,y\|_1 = |x| + |y|,$
and define a circle of radius $r$ about $(x_0,y_0)$ as the set of points $(x,y)$
satisfying $\|x-x_0, y-y_0\|_2 = r,$ 
then every "circle" is what we would usually view as a square with its diagonals
parallel to the axes.

If we use the metric $\|x,y\|_\infty = \max(|x|, |y|),$
so that the circle of radius $r$ about $(x_0,y_0)$ is defined
by $\|x-x_0, y-y_0\|_\infty = r,$ 
the "circle" is what we would usually regard as a square whose sides are parallel
to the axes.

But you would also require a definition of what it means for a figure to be a
"square" with respect to either the $\|\cdot\|_1$ measure or the  the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$
measure, and you would require a definition of "area" with respect to the same measure.